# Illegal Argument Exception at query index 70

Tags: android, http-post, android-button, http-get

I am trying to update my database field with some value with respect to value send from edit text values ...
My code is:

```
Intent myintent = getIntent();
//mdate = intent.getStringExtra("mdate");
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
title=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){ 
    mtitle = extras.getString("title");
    stime = extras.getString("mtime");
    sdate = extras.getString("mdate");
    cvenue = extras.getString("venue");
}

title.setText(mtitle);
title.setFocusable(false);
cdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
cdate.setText(sdate);
cdate.setFocusable(false);
venue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
venue.setText(cvenue);
venue.setFocusable(false);
ctime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
ctime.setText(stime);
ctime.setFocusable(false);
cnfrm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
cnfrm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          try {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Befor", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         get= new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/meetingschedular/confirmmeet.php?
                       res="+resy.toString()+"&title="+title.getText().toString()+"&
                       venue="+venue.getText().toString()+"&cdate="+cdate.getText()
                       .toString()+"&ctime="+ctime.getText().toString()+"&
                       attend="+uid.toString());
                 client= new DefaultHttpClient();
                 res=client.execute(get);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After res", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 in = res.getEntity().getContent();
         StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
                 int ch;
                 while((ch=in.read())!=-1) {
                       str.append((char)ch);
                 }
                 String tmp=str.toString();
                 tmp=tmp.trim();
                 //txt.setText(tmp);
                 if(flag.equals(tmp)) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tmp, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } else {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry cannot confirm", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
           } catch(Exception e) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
     }
});
```

My php code:

```
 <?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('meetingschedulardata',$con);
if(!$con)
{
die("can not connect".mysql_error());
}
$title=$_GET['title'];
$cdate=$_GET['cdate'];
$ctime=$_GET['ctime'];
$attend=$_GET['attend'];
$venue=$_GET['venue'];
$res=$_GET['res'];
$sdate = strtotime($cdate);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', $sdate);
$stime = strtotime($ctime);
$new_time = date('h:i:s', $stime);
$order="Update meetingdetails SET status='$res' WHERE status IS NULL AND
         title='$title' AND mdate='$new_date' AND mtime='$new_time' AND
           attendees='$attend' AND venue='$venue'";
$result=mysql_query($order,$con);
if($result==1)
{
echo "true";
}
else{
echo "false".mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Whenever I'm trying to click on my confirm button its giving this error ..
[image]

I'm not getting where actually is my error. PLs hlp me. Thnx in advance.

Comment: StackTrace ? Line where you get error ?

Comment: Show us your query printed please

Comment: i dint get your ques which query u want to see.. i have given my php code as well java code.. i am not geetinh what exactly u want @ZouZou

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with the character at pos 70 in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in log :

> IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query

means you are passing wrong characters in QueryString with URL. use `URLEncoder.encode` for encoding parameters before making request.try it as:

```
String str_params=URLEncoder.encode(res="+resy.toString()+
                              "&title="+title.getText().toString()+
                              "&venue="+venue.getText().toString()+
                              "&cdate="+cdate.getText().toString()+
                              "&ctime="+ctime.getText().toString()+
                              "&attend="+uid.toString(),"UTF-8");
get= new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/meetingschedular/confirmmeet.php?"
                                                            +str_params);
```